# Log Analyics adding Customer dimensions possible via powershell?

Tags: json, azure, powershell, azure-log-analytics

Hello I am trying to add a custom dimension or something similar called properties. Below I added a printscreen so something similar found online

[image]

Here is the code I used to try and create this

```
$JSON = @{
    Type             = 'SQL'
    Subscriptionname = "123"
    property         = @{
        SQLServerName       = "myServer";
        DatabaseName        = "myDatabase";
 
    }
}

$json2 = $JSON | ConvertTo-Json
# $json2

# Submit the data to the API endpoint
Post-LogAnalyticsData -customerId $customerId -sharedKey $sharedKey -body ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($json2)) -logType "MyRecordTypetoo"
```

But the results came out like below

[image]

Anyone have any ideas to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Please the follow the below ways to fix the issue:

#### Way 1

- using [keithbabinec](https://github.com/keithbabinec)/**[AzurePowerShellUtilityFunctions](https://github.com/keithbabinec/AzurePowerShellUtilityFunctions)** Git Hub repo

```
#Import the AzurePowerShell Utility Function file from above github repo

Import-Module AzurePowerShellUtilityFunctions.psd1

#  Adding custom properties using Event Telemetry

Send-AppInsightsEventTelemetry -InstrumentationKey '<Instrumentation Key of AI>' -EventName <Event Name> -CustomProperties @{ '<Custom Property>' = '<Property Value>'}
```

#### Way 2

- Using **[PSModule](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSAppInsights/)**

For adding custom dimension in application insights, we have [PSModule](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzurePowerShellUtilityFunctions/1.2/Content/Functions%5CPublic%5CSend-AppInsightsEventTelemetry.ps1) to add the properties in application Insights. Refer [here](https://vnextengineer.azurewebsites.net/powershell-application-insights/) for the detailed steps.

#### Way 3

- Using **RESTAPI**
  I Hope you already tried with the same. By calling the **RestAPI** as same mentioned in the above PowerShell module.

#### Result

[image]

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same thing but with log analytics. Will the AI query work for LA?

Comment: Yes, query works in Log Analytics